# Ellipsis issue with firefox only

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am using firefox version 23 & there are 3 elements which should show ellipses when the text overflows. This works in chrome but in mozilla firefox only one element shows ellipses.
Please check jsfiddle below.

This is my html code

```
    <h1 class="title2" >Course  11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 2222222222222222221111111111111111111111</h1>
<h1 class="title1" >Unit  11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 22222222222222221111111111111111111111111</h1>
<h2 class="title2" >Assignment 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</h2>
```

This is my css code

```
    h1.title1 {
    font: 12px/0px 'proximanovaRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 12px 12px 12px 20px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    width:200px;
}

h1.title2 {
    font: 12px/0px 'proximanovaRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 12px 12px 12px 20px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    width:200px;
}

h2.title2 {
    font: 34px/15px 'akzidenz-grotesk_bq_condensMd', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 12px 12px 12px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #1d6a9c, 2px 2px 0px #1d6a9c;

        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    width:200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gaurav14u/ELyHW/5/ 
If I open run this jsfiddle in chrome then it works but in ff it does not add ellipses for first 2 elements.

Comment: I have had his problem in the past too, I haven't found out why it works in Chrome (& Opera) and not in FF. But try adding 1px line height (that is `font: 12px/1px`) and it should work in FF too.

Comment: @Harry You are supposed to do only code formatting. The way you did edit above might change the OP's code. (you removed some spaces) I rolled back your changes. (let the OP know before you do like this).. :)

Comment: @Harry Take it light pal. It has been taken cared :).

Answer (score 1):

Please add 1px line-height to your `font` css rule (like `font: 12px/1px`) and that should solve the issue in Firefox.

(**Note:** This is only a work-around solution and I have no idea on why it works in Chrome/Opera but not in FireFox. I will update the answer if I manage to find out the reason.)

Comment: Just so you know, that doesn't work on my version of Firefox (4.0 on a Mac)

Comment: @MichaelPeterson That is interesting, I am on Windows 8 with FF 22.0. The `text-overflow: ellipsis` does work for me with atleast 1px line-height.

Comment: This [**link**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) from w3schools indicates that the property works on all major browsers.

Comment: Yeah, just upgraded to FF 23.0 and it works now. I don't normally use FF so it must have been a very old version.